# Unsupported version control system when I try to resync trac with svn

Tags: python-2.7, svn, trac

I just finishing installing

- Windows server 2016 x64
- Apache 2.2 (x86)
- Python 27 (x86)
- subversion 1.9.7 (from visualsvn 3.8 x64 because Win server don't accept x86 version)
- Trac 1.2.2

This a part of my trac.ini configuration for svn

```
[components]
tracopt.versioncontrol.svn.* = enabled

[repositories]
proj_web.dir = C:\Repositories\proj_web
proj_web.description = This is the ''main'' project repository.
proj_web.type = svn
proj_web.url = http://192.168.0.55:8080/svn/proj_web/

.alias = proj_web
```

SVN is working, trac also but I want now to synchronize trac with svn (migration), so I'm using the command:

```
trac-admin C:\Trac\proj_web repository resync proj_web
```

and the error was:

> InvalidConnector: Unsupported version control system "svn": DLL load failed:

How can I know which dll failed to load ?
Someone have an idea of the problem?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try loading the svn bindings from your Python interpreter. Open a Python shell and run: `from svn import core`.

If that fails, then you either need to modify your path, or use an x64 build of Python. I'd first try changing to an x64 build of Python. There's a troubleshooting checklist on the [TracSubversion](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracSubversion#Checklist) page, but it's probably a little out-of-date.

Comment: Thanks @RjOllos. When i try to run from svn import core i have errors : <br/><code> from svn import core
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\svn\core.py", line 26, in <module>
    from libsvn.core import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\libsvn\core.py", line 25, in <module>
    _core = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\libsvn\core.py", line 21, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_core', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed ...<code/>

Comment: That looks consistent with an x64/x86 mismatch or PYTHONPATH issue.